# Countifs on Quicksight

Tags: syntax, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

What's the equivalent function on Quicksight like "Countifs" on Excel? I would like to create a calculated field to add the count if Order status = Created AND Order status = Paid. What would be the syntax? Many thanks in advance!

| Order status | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Created | 45 |
| Paid | 50 |
| Closed | 10 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
countIf({Count}, {Order status} = "Created" OR {Order status} = "Paid")
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/countIf-function.html